# I have to double click a button in order for a function to work in js

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to implement a simple speech to text and then text to speech as a response to the initial speech to text input!

I'm using code from another open source site for both the speech synthesis and text 2 speech, so I don't fully understand the code.

Basically, what is happening is that when I am finished speaking the input, I press the `pause-record-btn` which is supposed to trigger `myFunction()`, yet I have to press the button twice!

(I am VERY new to js but do understand a bit of front end development (css, html) so any help will be very appreciated )

[Code Pen](https://codepen.io/Away007/pen/bKXvRR)

```js
/*-----------------------------
      Voice Recognition Script 
------------------------------*/

try {
  var SpeechRecognition = window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition;
  var recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
}
catch(e) {
  console.error(e);
  $('.no-browser-support').show();
  $('.app').hide();
}


var noteTextarea = $('#note-textarea');
var instructions = $('#recording-instructions');
var notesList = $('ul#notes');

var noteContent = '';

// Get all notes from previous sessions and display them.
var notes = getAllNotes();
renderNotes(notes);



/*-----------------------------
      Voice Recognition 
------------------------------*/

// If false, the recording will stop after a few seconds of silence.
// When true, the silence period is longer (about 15 seconds),
// allowing us to keep recording even when the user pauses. 
recognition.continuous = true;

// This block is called every time the Speech APi captures a line. 
recognition.onresult = function(event) {

  // event is a SpeechRecognitionEvent object.
  // It holds all the lines we have captured so far. 
  // We only need the current one.
  var current = event.resultIndex;

  // Get a transcript of what was said.
  var transcript = event.results[current][0].transcript;

  // Add the current transcript to the contents of our Note.
  // There is a weird bug on mobile, where everything is repeated twice.
  // There is no official solution so far so we have to handle an edge case.
  var mobileRepeatBug = (current == 1 && transcript == event.results[0][0].transcript);

  if(!mobileRepeatBug) {
    noteContent += transcript;
    noteTextarea.val(noteContent);
  }
};

recognition.onstart = function() { 
  instructions.text('Voice recognition activated. Try speaking into the microphone.');
}

recognition.onspeechend = function() {
  instructions.text('You were quiet for a while so voice recognition turned itself off.');
}

recognition.onerror = function(event) {
  if(event.error == 'no-speech') {
    instructions.text('No speech was detected. Try again.');  
  };
}



/*-----------------------------
      App buttons and input 
------------------------------*/

$('#start-record-btn').on('click', function(e) {
  if (noteContent.length) {
    noteContent += ' ';
  }
  recognition.start();
});


$('#pause-record-btn').on('click', function(e) {
  recognition.stop();
  instructions.text('Voice recognition paused.');
});








// Sync the text inside the text area with the noteContent variable.
noteTextarea.on('input', function() {
  noteContent = $(this).val();
})

$('#save-note-btn').on('click', function(e) {
  recognition.stop();

  if(!noteContent.length) {
    instructions.text('Could not save empty note. Please add a message to your note.');
  }
  else {
    // Save note to localStorage.
    // The key is the dateTime with seconds, the value is the content of the note.
    saveNote(new Date().toLocaleString(), noteContent);

    // Reset variables and update UI.
    noteContent = '';
    renderNotes(getAllNotes());
    noteTextarea.val('');
    instructions.text('Note saved successfully.');
  }
      
})


notesList.on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var target = $(e.target);

  // Listen to the selected note.
  if(target.hasClass('listen-note')) {
    var content = target.closest('.note').find('.content').text();
    readOutLoud(content);
  }

  // Delete note.
  if(target.hasClass('delete-note')) {
    var dateTime = target.siblings('.date').text();  
    deleteNote(dateTime);
    target.closest('.note').remove();
  }
});



/*-----------------------------
      Speech Synthesis 
------------------------------*/

function readOutLoud(message) {
 var speech = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();

  // Set the text and voice attributes.
 speech.text = message;
 speech.volume = 1;
 speech.rate = 1;
 speech.pitch = 1;
  
 window.speechSynthesis.speak(speech);
}



/*-----------------------------
      Helper Functions 
------------------------------*/

function renderNotes(notes) {
  var html = '';
  if(notes.length) {
    notes.forEach(function(note) {
      html+= `<li class="note">
        <p class="header">
          <span class="date">${note.date}</span>
          <a href="#" class="listen-note" title="Listen to Note">Listen to Note</a>
          <a href="#" class="delete-note" title="Delete">Delete</a>
        </p>
        <p class="content">${note.content}</p>
      </li>`;    
    });
  }
  else {
    html = '<li><p class="content">You don\'t have any notes yet.</p></li>';
  }
  notesList.html(html);
}


function saveNote(dateTime, content) {
  localStorage.setItem('note-' + dateTime, content);
}


function getAllNotes() {
  var notes = [];
  var key;
  for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
    key = localStorage.key(i);

    if(key.substring(0,5) == 'note-') {
      notes.push({
        date: key.replace('note-',''),
        content: localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i))
      });
    } 
  }
  return notes;
}


function deleteNote(dateTime) {
  localStorage.removeItem('note-' + dateTime); 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Voice Controlled Notes App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src='https://code.responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice.js'></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/shoelace-css/1.0.0-beta16/shoelace.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">

            <h1>Voice Controlled Notes App</h1>
            <p class="page-description">A tiny app that allows you to take notes by recording your voice</p>
            <h3 class="no-browser-support">Sorry, Your Browser Doesn't Support the Web Speech API. Try Opening This Demo In Google Chrome.</h3>

            <div class="app"> 
                <h3>Add New Note</h3>
                <div class="input-single">
                    <textarea id="note-textarea" placeholder="Input." rows="6"></textarea>
                </div>
                <button id="start-record-btn" title="Start Recording">Start Recognition</button>         
                <button id="pause-record-btn" onClick="myFunction()" title="Pause Recording">Stop listening</button>
                <p id="recording-instructions">Press the <strong>Start Recognition</strong> button and allow access.</p>
                
            </div>

        </div>
        

        <p id="demo"></p>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>

        <script>

            function myFunction() {
                var str = document.getElementById("note-textarea").value;
                if (str.includes("hello how are you")){
                    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "hi anthony";
                    responsiveVoice.speak("I am good thanks,       and you?");
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Once I press Start, I only have to press Stop once, after which it says `You were quiet for a while so voice recognition turned itself off.`, on Chrome 66. The listener seems to trigger the first time, at least for me

Comment: hey sorry the question wasnt clear its the response that the button is supposed to triger

Comment: hey! did you update the question! to reflect what you just said in your COMMENT!!